# 3D plots and grid.arrange in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d, gridextra

I am attempting to graph three 3D plots and displaying all three at the same time. For the other plots I have been using the grid.arrange function from the package gridExtra. However, I am getting an error with my 3D plots. The error I am getting reads: "Error in gList(list(xyz.convert = function (x, y = NULL, z = NULL)  : only 'grobs' allowed in "gList""

My code looks somethings like this:

```
cont1<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(300), nrow=10, ncol=3))
pre1<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(300), nrow=10, ncol=3))
post1<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(300), nrow=10, ncol=3))

library(scatterplot3d)
attach(as.data.frame(cont1))
p<-scatterplot3d(X1,X2,X3, main="3D Scatterplot")
fit <- lm(X3 ~ X1+X2) 
p$plane3d(fit)


attach(as.data.frame(pre1))
l<-scatterplot3d(X1,X2,X3, main="3D Scatterplot")
fit <- lm(X3 ~ X1+X2) 
l$plane3d(fit)


attach(as.data.frame(post1))
m<-scatterplot3d(X1,X2,X3, main="3D Scatterplot")
fit <- lm(X3 ~ X1+X2) 
m$plane3d(fit)

require(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p,l,m)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: First, your example is not reproducible. `x`, `y`, and `z` are not defined. Second, the `attach` is not necessary in this scenario. Third, why not  use `par(mfrow)`, e.g., `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` or `par(mfrow=c(1,3))`, etc? I think grid.arrange is meant for arranging ggplot opjects not base plots.

Comment: I edited it to make it reproducible. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that `grid.arrange` can be used with anything by ggplot2 plots... Here is a potential solution using `par`. If you want a 1x3 arrangement set `mfrow=c(1,3)` or a 3x1, `mfrow=c(3,1)`

```
library(gridExtra)
library(scatterplot3d)

cont1<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(300), nrow=10, ncol=3))
pre1<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(300), nrow=10, ncol=3))
post1<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(300), nrow=10, ncol=3))

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
p<-with(cont1, scatterplot3d(X1,X2,X3, main="3D Scatterplot"))
fit <- lm(X3 ~ X1+X2) 
p$plane3d(fit)

l<-with(pre1, scatterplot3d(X1,X2,X3, main="3D Scatterplot"))
fit <- lm(X3 ~ X1+X2) 
l$plane3d(fit)

m<-with(post1, scatterplot3d(X1,X2,X3, main="3D Scatterplot"))
fit <- lm(X3 ~ X1+X2) 
m$plane3d(fit)
```

[image]

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: `grid.arrange()` can be used with grid-based graphics, not just ggplot2. `scatterplot3d` uses base graphics. It's possible to mix the two systems, but in this particular case it makes sense to stick with pure base graphics and use layout functions such as `par(mfrow)`